# Can anyone indetify this SMD component?

Tags: transistors, resistors, diodes, surface-mount, pcb-assembly

This is from N9005 phone and i would love to know what SMD component is this. Here is a photo. Thank[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5nao.jpg)

Comment: maybe a PTC fuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SMD capacitor and inductor seems to be same in physical appearance.
It difficult to what it is ,just by seeing it.

  Use a multi-meter to test it.Put to continuity and touch the two leads of the component.If you see first continuity and slowly goes to open circuit,it'll be capacitor.If it shows resistance value,so it's a resistor with that value.If you see resistance less than 2.0 Ohm(at the maximum),then it'll be a diode.If it reads closed circuit,then it'll a inductor.

  Mostly in resistor a value was already written in it.But I don't know that symbol near 11.

  Hope this method will help to figure it ,what it is.

Comment: Is it a damaged one,or good one?

Comment: Hey, from my N910F Phone is damaged one but it seems like its not effecting the phone at all, but still i want to repair it. So i found out that in my N9005 phone has the same. I tried a resistance an its seems like its 1.7M ohms.

Comment: If it doesn't goes to open circuit means surely it not capacitor.This seems it's resistor with resistance value is 1.7 M ohms only.There are smd resistors in mega ohm range.I don't think so that they wont use diac in mobile phones.Also,Is the component placed near some heat releasing place in the phone?I suspect it may be thermistor,if it's near heat emitting place of the phone or near the processor.